# Segmentation fault (core dumped) informix

Tags: sql, node.js, informix

im using node informix module which can be found here https://github.com/nukedzn/node-informix,
below is my sample code,

```
let opts = {
database : "sampling@myserver",
username : "informix",
password : "xxxxxxx"
}

let informix = require("informix")(opts)
let create_table = CREATE RAW TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dumb (test_id SERIAL,age INT,value BSON);
let inservalues = INSERT INTO dumb(test_id,age,value) VALUES (0, 50, '{math:"80"}'::JSON);
let select_table = SELECT value::JSON FROM dumb;

informix
.query(select_table)
.then(cursor => cursor.fetchAll( { close : true } ))
.then(result => {
console.log(result);
})
```

cant get value from bson datatype

```
error : Segmentation fault (core dumped),
```

when i run the query

```
SELECT value::JSON FROM dumb;
```

In dbaccess, i got

```
(expression) {"math":"80"}
```

any idea whats happening here ?
thank you

Comment: In [JSON](http://json.org/), you should quote the key (name) of each name/value pair: `'{"math":80}'` for a numeric value, or `{"math":"80"}'` for a string value.  That shouldn't cause a crash though — an error is entirely acceptable, but a crash is not.

Comment: the problem is i want to get the data store in informix database which is (expression) {"math":"80"}, but i cant, ist because the informix module cant recognize what type of the variable is ? or dunno what to do with this kind of variable ? cause sometimes i got this error error Error: [-1821] Host variable is not large enough to hold the data returned from the server,

Comment: i just simply want to console.log the bson data in informix database, and use that data for my app,

Comment: Try: `SELECT value::JSON::LVARCHAR FROM dumb;` — that should convert from (unknown) JSON to (known) LVARCHAR.  With luck you don't need to specify a size; if you're unlucky, you might need to specify a size: `SELECT value::JSON::LVARCHAR(2048) FROM dumb;` or similar, hoping that you don't have to go too big.  I think the unsized version will be OK, but I'm not certain.

Comment: no luck, i got this following error ...
Error: [-1820] Host variable type has been changed between fetches or puts.
it is because of node modules that im using or something else cause it
i have no idea whats happening, im still very new to informix

Comment: That’s a pain.  It may be that we’re confusing Node.  I don’t usually touch Node (or anything else using JavaScript) as a programmer. That means I have limited experience and knowledge to help you.

Comment: no problem, thanks for already reaching out,